# typeMismatch.target spring boot batch rejected value [2020-09-18T00:00:00+02:00]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, timestamp-with-timezone

I am trying to integrate data from CSV file with spring boot using a batch,
I have a problem with the date field because it is constantly rejected regardless of the type used,
**here is my code:**

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String service;
    private Timestamp time;
```

```
    @Override
    public IndProd process(final IndProd indProd) throws Exception {
        String service = indProd.getService();
        Timestamp time = indProd.getTime();
        Long nbAppels = indProd.getNbAppels();
        Integer tempsDeReponseMoyenMillisecondes = indProd.getTempsDeReponseMoyenMillisecondes();
        Long volume = indProd.getVolume();
        BigDecimal tempsDeReponseMoyenSecondes = indProd.getTempsDeReponseMoyenSecondes();
        IndProd transformedIndProd = new IndProd(service,time,nbAppels,tempsDeReponseMoyenMillisecondes,volume,tempsDeReponseMoyenSecondes);

        return transformedIndProd;
    }
```

**here is the error returned:**

> Caused by: org.springframework.validation.BindException:
> org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
> Field error in object 'target' on field 'time': rejected value
> [2020-09-18T00:00:00+02:00]; codes
> [typeMismatch.target.time,typeMismatch.time,typeMismatch.java.sql.Timestamp,typeMismatch];
> arguments
> [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
> codes [target.time,time]; arguments []; default message [time]];
> default message [Failed to convert property value of type
> 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Timestamp' for property
> 'time'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot
> convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
> 'java.sql.Timestamp' for property 'time': no matching editors or
> conversion strategy found]    at
> org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.mapFieldSet(BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.java:201)
> ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper.mapLine(DefaultLineMapper.java:43)
> ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:185)
> ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]    ... 56
> common frames omitted

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, it clear that `indProd.getTime()` returns a `String` value which you are trying to assign to a `Timestamp` variable. Assuming `indProd.getTime()` returns a date-time string in the format, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX` e.g. `2020-09-18T00:00:00+02:00` (as mentioned in the title of your question), you should replace

```
Timestamp time = indProd.getTime();
```

with

```
Timestamp time = new Timestamp(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX").parse(indProd.getTime()).getTime());
```

**Note:** `java.sql.Timestamp` extends `java.util.Date` and the date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. I suggest you should stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

**Using the modern date-time API:**

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(indProd.getTime());
//...
IndProd transformedIndProd = new IndProd(service,odt,nbAppels,tempsDeReponseMoyenMillisecondes,volume,tempsDeReponseMoyenSecondes);
```

and declare the instance members as

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String service;
private OffsetDateTime odt;// Change the type to OffsetDateTime
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 0):

As the error said you are trying to assign a String value to an Instant variable.
That mean `indProd.getTime()` is trying to be String.

One way to fix this is to retype to String back to instant, it is maybe not the best solution but is should work.

```
Timestamp time = Timestamp.from(ZonedDateTime.parse(indProd.getTime()).toInstant());
```

and in `IndProd` variable change time to String